# Symfony make:entity annotation mapping error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I want to create a new entity in my ORO platform application by using the make:entity command from the MakerBundle.

I expect it to create an entity in my bundle `Acme\Bundle\TestBundle` which I set in my `config_dev.yml` by using:

```
maker:
    root_namespace: 'Acme\Bundle\TestBundle'
```

So I execute

```
bin/console make:entity Test
```

which returns

```
 ! [NOTE] It looks like your app may be using a namespace other than "Acme\Bundle\TestBundle".                 
 !                                                                                                                      
 !        To configure this and make your life easier, see:                                                             
 !        https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html#configuration                           

 created: src/Acme/Bundle/TestBundle/Entity/Test.php
 created: src/Acme/Bundle/TestBundle/Repository/TestRepository.php


 [ERROR] Only annotation mapping is supported by make:entity, but the                                                   
         <info>Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Test</info> class uses a different format. If you would like   
         this command to generate the properties & getter/setter methods, add your mapping configuration, and then      
         re-run this command with the <info>--regenerate</info> flag.
```

I've tried to run the command once again, which works. But obviously this is not the way how it's meant to work. So how can I fix this mapping error?

Comment: Where did you define the structure of your entity? Through the console or in configuration?

Comment: @El_Vanja I am sorry, what do you mean by my entity structure?

Comment: Properties and their types.

Comment: @El_Vanja Oooh! Yeah I defined them by using the console. When I create a new entity for the first time, it gives me the error. But when I run the same command a second time I get the interactive console where I can enter my properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started with the standard Symfony 5 project by using `Symfony new myapp`.

I add the config file in `config/packages/dev/maker.yaml`

```
maker:
    root_namespace: 'App\Core'
```

To generate the entity in the `src/Core` folder, I got the following error:

```
➜ symfony console make:entity Post

 created: src/Core/Entity/Post.php
 created: src/Core/Repository/PostRepository.php


 [ERROR] Only annotation mapping is supported by make:entity, but the <info>App\Core\Entity\Post</info> class uses
         a different format. If you would like this command to generate the properties & getter/setter methods, add your
         mapping configuration, and then re-run this command with the <info>--regenerate</info> flag.
```

To avoid showing the error in the console, I install the patch created by `vklux / maker-bundle-force-annotation`

### Step 1: install package

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

### Step 2: apply the patch in `composer.json`

```
{
    // {...} composer.json content
    "extra": {
        "patches": {
            "symfony/maker-bundle": {
                "Provide flag to force annotation in make entity command": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vklux/maker-bundle-force-annotation/master/maker-force-annotation-flag.patch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Step 3: composer update

```
composer update
```

### Step 4: try `make:entity` with the additional command option

```
➜ symfony console make:entity Post --force-annotation

 created: src/Core/Entity/Post.php
 created: src/Core/Repository/PostRepository.php

 Entity generated! Now let's add some fields!
 You can always add more fields later manually or by re-running this command.

 New property name (press <return> to stop adding fields):
 >
```

✅   Everything works fine now.

Comment: Here I was thinking it wasn't possible to fix it. But you prove otherwise! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: ``Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch...``

Comment: I think you just need to add mapping in doctrine.yml file. No need to apply ani patches.
 
for example:
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in the doctrine version please try this version good luck

```
composer req doctrine/doctrine-bundle:2.2
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you

Comment: Now fixed with v1.30.2

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to create new entities with Symfony maker using **doctrine/doctrine-bundle** version higher than **2.2.4**

These steps worked for me with:

- `"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7"`
- PHP 8.1 (I migrate from php 7.4 in my case)

**STEP 1:** replace `type: annotation` by `type: attribute` inside `doctrine.yaml`

**STEP 2:** Enter entity root with namespace:

```
symfony console make:entity  App\Entity\test
```

[image]